# SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: This ALTER TABLE command is not yet supported

Tags: yugabytedb

I am new to YugabyteDB. I have a table T1 and column col1 and col2 (having primary key) .If i am trying to run ALTER TABLE to change data type of col1 i am getting error like given below .

Query :- ALTER TABLE "T1" ALTER COLUMN "COL1" TYPE VARCHAR(20);

Error:- SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: This ALTER TABLE command is not yet supported.

All this i am doing from DBeaver.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't yet available because it often (like in this case) requires a table rewrite, which is very expensive in a distributed environment with synchronous replication. You can track the progress of the issue here: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/1013

Comment: what is the alternate for this problem .Is drop and again create  table is only way to resolve this problem ?

Comment: For development yes. In production, you can create a new table, migrate writes by writing to both tables, and then migrate reads by reading only on the new table and stop reading from the old table, and then dropping the old table.